# Pandas DataFrame select rows based on values of multiple columns whose names are specified in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ds = pd.DataFrame({'z':np.random.binomial(n=1,p=0.5,size=10), 
                   'x':np.random.binomial(n=1,p=0.5,size=10), 
                   'u':np.random.binomial(n=1,p=0.5,size=10), 
                   'y':np.random.binomial(n=1,p=0.5,size=10)})
ds
```

```
    z   x   u   y
0   0   1   0   0
1   0   1   1   1
2   1   1   1   1
3   0   0   1   1
4   0   0   1   1
5   0   0   0   0
6   1   0   1   1
7   0   1   1   1
8   1   1   0   0
9   0   1   1   1
```

How do I select rows that have the values (0,1) for variable names specified in a list?

This is what I have thus far:

```
zs = ['z','x']
tf = ds[ds[zs].values == (0,1)]
tf
```

Now that prints:

```
    z   x   u   y
0   0   1   0   0
0   0   1   0   0
1   0   1   1   1
1   0   1   1   1
2   1   1   1   1
3   0   0   1   1
4   0   0   1   1
5   0   0   0   0
7   0   1   1   1
7   0   1   1   1
8   1   1   0   0
9   0   1   1   1
9   0   1   1   1
```

Which shows duplicates and also has incorrect row (row #2 - 1,1,1,1). Any thoughts or ideas? Of course I am assuming there is a pythonic way of doing this without nested loops and brute-forcing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use broadcasted numpy comparison:

```
df[(df[['z','x']].values == [0, 1]).all(1)]

   z  x  u  y
0  0  1  0  0
1  0  1  1  1
7  0  1  1  1
9  0  1  1  1
```

---

You can also use `np.logical_and.reduce`:

```
cols = ['z', 'x']
vals = [0, 1]

df[np.logical_and.reduce([df[c] == v for c, v in zip(cols, vals)])]

   z  x  u  y
0  0  1  0  0
1  0  1  1  1
7  0  1  1  1
9  0  1  1  1
```

---

Lastly, assuming your column names are compatible, dynamically generate query expression strings for use with `query`:

```
querystr = ' and '.join([f'{c} == {v!r}' for c,  v in zip(cols, vals)])
df.query(querystr)

   z  x  u  y
0  0  1  0  0
1  0  1  1  1
7  0  1  1  1
9  0  1  1  1
```

Where `{v!r}` is the same as `{repr(v)}`.

Comment: Thank you @coldspeed. It's very helpful. Do you know why my simplistic query gives the wrong answer (duplicates and an erroneous row)?

Comment: @vsm You were close. You need a 1D mask to index `df`. So, with your solution, you should have done `(df[['z', 'x']].values == (0, 1)).all(axis=1)` to see which row satisfied this condition for all columns. That's why this was my first option—to show you your fixed code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
cols = ['u','x']
bools = ds[cols].apply(lambda x: all(x == (0,1)), axis=1)
ds[bools]

   u  x  y  z
0  0  1  1  1
7  0  1  0  1
8  0  1  1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `eq` , and very similar to cold's numpy method

```
df[df[zs].eq(pd.Series([0,1],index=zs),1).all(1)]
   z  x  u  y
0  0  1  0  0
1  0  1  1  1
7  0  1  1  1
9  0  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to use **boolean indexing**:

```
f = ds['z'] == 0
g = ds['x'] == 1
ds[f & g]
```

Comment: "simple" but does not scale for multiple columns and values. See `np.logical_and.reduce` on how to generalise it (also, see the second option of my answer).